# phpMyAdmin 4.0.5 export error bug - anyone know if it is being addressed?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export, cpanel

phpMyAdmin has announced that in a few days on Sept 1st 2013 they're closing down their other resources such as mailing list and forums and are deferring us to use StackOverflow / StackExchange.

I provide general support at a small cPanel hosting service and part of my duties include doing frequent DB Exports in phpMyAdmin and also showing hosting customers how to export their databases from phpMyAdmin within their cPanel as a backup tool.

Been working fine for many years and across many servers / cPanel versions / PHP  versions / mysQL versions.

**But after we recently upgraded to phpMyAdmin 4.0.5 final** (we use WHM's EasyApache to keep PHP and other server modules updated regularly) **we're encountering an apparent bug and cannot Export databases.**

**Any attempt to Export a DB** over a certain size (haven't determined exactly yet, but seems to be around 20MB) instead of getting the usual download prompt, it simply immediately **fails**.

If the Export is attempted in FireFox the error looks like this:

```
Firefox can't find the file at https://example.example.net:2083/cpsess1210889896/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/export.php
```

If the Export is attempted in Internet Explorer simply says `"The website cannot display the page"` and when more info is clicked says:

```
This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.
```

Since upgrading to 4.0.5 that just started happening with DB's that I've been exporting through phpMyAdmin for years, literally, with no problem before.

I tried raising some memory limits within WHM / cPanel such as the max memory cPanel session can use, but it doesn't help. Also a couple of discussions on the cPanel forums seem to be claiming that this problem stems from a bug in phpMyAdmin, not a problem with cPanel or PHP.

Can anyone shed any more light on this problem?

Is there anyone from phpMyAdmin who knows if this specific issue is being addressed?

Thanks very much for any help or feedback that anyone here is willing to provide. This is putting me in a bit of a jam with our clients.

Just in case it matters here is the general server environment:

```
cPanel/WHM 11.38.2 (build 6)
Apache 2.2.25
PHP 5.4.18
mySQL 5.5.32-cll
RHEL 5 64bit
running suPHP
```

EDIT - I forgot to mention that the problem occurs whether doing a straight "Quick" SQL export and/or a "Custom" compressed export (such as a gzip). Either way, quick or compressed we can't export databases larger than around 20MB.

**UPDATE / FIX - Marc Delisle's code changes in phpMyAdmin 4.0.6 fixes this bug, and after cPanel 11.38.2.7 "Release" came out recently it has resolved the issues on my servers. Thank you Marc and the PMA team!**

Comment: First, yes you are at the correct place for support. Second, I just did a quick test with phpMyAdmin 4.0.5 and exported a table, producing a 23 MB file. This is on PHP 5.4.4. I don't have the same server environment than yours and this will require more tests. By the way, from which phpMyAdmin version did you upgrade? and are you doing a quick export in SQL format? with or without compression?

Comment: I made more tests, comparing with version 3.5.x and I confirm that there is a problem in 4.0.5. With 3.5.8 I was able to export a 130 MB file and it started immediately to export.

Comment: Thank you for testing and confirming the problem Marc. To try to answer your questions - I honestly don't recall for sure which version we upgraded from but I believe it was 3.5.8 (if not, then an early 4.0.x), and the problem occurs in both methods - quick SQL and custom with gzip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix I propose for the upcoming 4.0.6-rc2, please confirm:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/5298602f8edb4475fce5d299532c7780e0e314a5.patch

Comment: Thank you Marc. I wish I could confirm and test it for you but I'm not on your level of expertise with phpMyAdmin. I depend on WHM/cPanel and EasyApache for the way things are compiled and updated on our servers. Perhaps someone else will stumble upon this and know how to confirm your proposed fix. Many thanks for your attention to this bug and your efforts.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly related to https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4046/

Does your webserver error log contain any hints?

Comment: Seems to be very related to that bug case 4046 , since as you can see Marc Delisle did some tests after viewing my post here, and then he confirmed that an upcoming fix is on the priority list at http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4046/#7ebe

I'm glad he has confirmed the issue, since I cannot find any clues in the server error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Good news for cPanel users who have been affected by this bug.

I was reading the cPanel Change Log and noticed that they are including PMA update to version 4.0.6 (which has Marc Delisle's fix) in the upcoming cPanel 11.38.2.7 update.

That means for most of WHM/cPanel runners the problem will be resolved likely by end of next week.

Answer (score 0):

In my case whas the size of the database, when i export all the tables (40MB) it return the error, but if i choose to get the database as a ZIP it works perfectly ;)