# Attempting database export yields webpage not found error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, export, backup

First time I get this problem after backing up over five years. After setting up custom export and hitting 'go' the message is:

> the webpage not found

I proceed to 'more' and get this message:

> No webpage was found for the web address: http://name.com/cpsess3961873665/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/export.php
>
> Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I tried two databases in my database list that behave normally as I am able to add info to my blog. I am backing up a Wordpress blog.

My last backup is 27 July 2013.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to work out what is wrong. Perhaps talk to your host to see if anything has changed?

Answer (score 1):

An export problem with large tables has been fixed in phpMyAdmin 4.0.6.

Comment: More than 5 years later, under phpMyAdmin 4.8.3 and WHM/cPanel 76.0 the same exact issue made a come back :P

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14478 whose fix will appear in version 4.8.6.

Comment: Hope so! We'll see... Thanks :) I +1'ed you for the necromancy trouble ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell from the error you're getting that you're using cPanel, so if your host (or you) updates cPanel to 11.38.2.7 when it releases (likely by end of next week) it will update PMA on the server to Marc's fixed 4.0.6 and your problem will go away. I've updated my thread on this at [phpMyAdmin 4.0.5 export error bug - anyone know if it is being addressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497970/phpmyadmin-4-0-5-export-error-bug-anyone-know-if-it-is-being-addressed)

In the meantime you can Export your databases via ssh command line if you run the server, or you can have your host do it for you and have them put the backup file in your account like is discussed at http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/webpage-not-found-while-trying-export-db-case-75085-a-358542.html#post1454512